# Dynamic initialization of array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator, double-pointer

```
class MyClass
{
    int **a;
    int *b[];

    MyClass()
    {
        a = new int*[10];
        b = new int*[10];
    }
};
```

In the above code I get a compilation error at the 2nd line inside the constructor (b = new int*[10]). It says error: incompatible types in assignment of `int**' to`int*[0u]'

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to an array; you can initialize it or assign to its members.  Your `b` member is invalid anyway since it is illegal to have an array of size 0; the syntax `T b[]` can only be used where an aggregate initializer is immediately provided allowing the compiler to infer the length of the array.